# How can I edit multiple texture colors at once?

Tags: animation, objects, color

I started working with Blender recently and I'm currently making a drone animation consisting of 150 spheres. I wish to know if there's a more effective way of editing 150 texture colors at once, or if I need to edit each texture color individually.

I've attached an image for context. Thank you for your time.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While editing one of the materials in question in a *Shader Editor*, create a node group by selecting the relevant nodes, and pressing <kbd>Ctrl + G</kbd>. In the example below, I only selected an RGB node, grouped it, and changed its name to *COLOR*. You can enter into a group by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>, that's what you're seeing the in the lower part of the screenshot:

[image]

Once you have that node group, you can simply copy it <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>, switch to other materials and paste <kbd>Ctrl + V</kbd> it into their material setup. You can also add this node group via <kbd>Shift + A</kbd> *> Group > nodename*.

[image]

Now, when you make changes to that node group, it'll be updated for all its copies in the file, even if they're different materials.

[image]